# QML Column: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop

Tags: qt, qml

I have two problems with the following code.

1. If I'm using padding in the QML Column I get this message:

   ```
   QML Column: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop
   ```

   and the application becomes unresponsive. Also if I don't use anchors the problem does not appear, but the Rectangle inside the Column won't be stretched.
2. If I'm using anchors the Column's implicitWidth and impliciHeight will be zero which will result that the Rectangles won't be shown.

The Qt documentation says this:

> Also, since a Column automatically positions its children vertically, a child item within a Column should not set its y position or vertically anchor itself using the top, bottom, anchors.verticalCenter, fill or centerIn anchors.

Which means horizontal anchoring (left/right) is not prohibited.

Any idea what could be wrong?

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "green"
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        implicitWidth: col.implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: col.implicitHeight
        color: "blue"
        Column {
            spacing: 10
            //padding: 10 // causes: QML Column: possible QQuickItem::polish() loop
            id: col
            Rectangle {
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 25
            }
            Rectangle {
                //anchors.left: parent.left // uncommenting these anchors will result that the column's implicitWidth and implicitHeight will be 0
                //anchors.right: parent.right
                implicitWidth: 200
                implicitHeight: 25
            }
            Component.onCompleted: console.log("column, imp width: " + implicitWidth + ", imp height: " + implicitHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The padding works if you specify a width for the column. It appears to fail if trying to use the implicitWidth of the children. That might be a bug.

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to specify horizontal anchors and implicitWidth at the same time?

Comment: implicitWidth (just like sizeHint in Qt widgets) tells the item's preferred width. I have a several elements with different implicitWidths and I want to display them with the same visible width (using the widest) underneath each other, hence I'm using horizontal anchoring. A single item in a Column (which is pointless) will set the Column's implicitWidth and the padding is correct too.

Comment: Makes sense. Does a `ColumnLayout` work any better for you?

Comment: The computer says no!
QML Rectangle: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead. But I have a solution and I will post it soon.

Comment: BTW ColumnLayout works. It is not using padding but a container parent can be added to create padding if needed. Despite the warning message the anchoring works as expected. Suppressing that warning message could be the solution, but that is a different story. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Ponzifex could you please post your current solution? Actually, I'm more interested in your final visual result

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, `Ponzifex`'s code can be improved:

Remove reparenting and instead create a new default property alias like this:

```
Rectangle 
{ 
   default property alias data2: col.data

   data: 
   [ 
      Column 
      { 
        id: col; 
        onChildrenChanged: { ...calculate sizes, add bindings, etc... }
      } 
   ]
}
```

How this works:

- When in QML code you are nesting objects in another object, you are adding them to a property that is marked as `default` inside the parent object
- For `Item` and thus `Rectangle` the property called `data` is marked as `default`

  - That property contains a combined list of visual children and resources of `Item` / `Rectangle`
  - Thus normally nesting visual elements in `Rectangle` causes them to be added as that `Rectangle`'s visual children
  - So normally `Rectangle { Text {}; Timer{} }` ...
  - ...is equivalent to: `Rectangle { data: [ Text {}, Timer{} ] }`
- I changed that by creating a new property called `data2` and setting it as `default` for the `Rectangle`

  - `data2` is not related to `data` so its elements are not added to `Rectangle`'s visual children list
  - Instead I made `data2` an alias to `data` property of your `Column`
  - An `alias` property is just that - an alias - another name of the property, in this case - as a property of another object - but both name "point" to the same actual property an thus `Column`'s list of visual children
  - So all QML elements nested inside the `Rectangle` are added as visual children of the `Column`
- However, now I have a problem: I cannot just nest the `Column` into `Rectangle` in QML code because it would mean that the `Column` needs to be added as it's own child (which makes no sense)

  - So I have to assign `Rectangle`'s actual `data` property (which is no longer default so I have to write its name explicitly) thus adding the `Column` as a visual child of the `Rectangle`
- Now whenever `Rectangle`'s nested elements are added or removed (including by a `Repeater`), the `Column`'s `data` property changes, but since we are adding visual children `children` property also changes

  - So we can trigger recalculations and rebinding when `Column`'s `onChildrenChanged` signal fires (or `onDataChanged` if you want to also trigger on non-visual children aka `resources`)
  - You can skip elements which already have your bindings or just rebind them

As far as I know, this is supposed to be valid and supported QML syntax - just not the one you usually use - so it's ok to use it in production code, perhaps with a comment explaining what is happening

Answer (score 1):

### Padding

You attach elements to left and right edges of the column,
but then tell the column it should position its elements 10 pixels away from that border.

They then start to "fight" each other by each causing layout update and thus triggering each other.

You need to place an intermediate element to handle padding like that:

```
Column{ padding: 10; Column{ id: col; Rectangle{}; Rectangle{}; } }
```

### Anchors

Let's see what's actually happening

I inserted some debugging code in each element:

```
property string name: "..."//I named them: "green_rect", "blue_rect", "col", "top_rect", "bottom_rect"
onWidthChanged: console.log(name + " changed: w=" + width)
....
property string mydbgstr: "top_rect w=" + width + " h=" + height + " iw=" + implicitWidth + " ih=" + implicitHeight
onMydbgstrChanged: console.log(mydbgstr)
```

It prints a string when any of the properties changes

My window is 500x500

Initial layout - this remains the same for all cases:

```
// property change notifications removed since they are not interesting yet
qml: bottom_rect w=200 h=25 iw=200 ih=25
qml: top_rect w=100 h=25 iw=100 ih=25
qml: col w=0 h=0 iw=0 ih=0
qml: blue_rect w=0 h=0 iw=0 ih=0
qml: green_rect w=0 h=0 iw=0 ih=0
```

okay so anchors are not applied yet, and the column hasn't calculated its size yet, so elements simply assume h=ih w=iw

After that we see different conclusions:

#### Both top and bottom rectangles' anchors commented:

```
qml: col changed: w=200
qml: col changed: h=60 
qml: col changed: iw=200
qml: blue_rect changed: w=200
qml: blue_rect changed: iw=200
qml: blue_rect w=200 h=0 iw=200 ih=0

qml: col changed: ih=60
qml: col w=200 h=60 iw=200 ih=60
qml: blue_rect changed: h=60
qml: blue_rect changed: ih=60
qml: blue_rect w=200 h=60 iw=200 ih=60

qml: green_rect changed: w=500
qml: green_rect w=500 h=500 iw=0 ih=0
qml: green_rect changed: h=500
```

Result:

```
▀▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

Works as expected: column calculates its size based on combined children sizes,
then surrounding element also assumes that size

#### Only top rect's anchors uncommented:

```
// it appears that top rect adjusted itself to fit still-zero-width column
qml: top_rect changed: w=0   col.w=0 //uh oh, top_rect is now zero-sized
qml: top_rect w=0 h=25 iw=100 ih=25

// here col probably performed layout and determined its width based on bottom rect
// however for some reason its own signal got delayed (isn't shown)
// probably because children get priority

// top_rect anchors react to column layout:
qml: top_rect changed: w=200   col.w=200  //top_rect is properly sized again
qml: top_rect w=200 h=25 iw=100 ih=25

// here col appears to react to the first layout change: 
qml: col changed: w=200
qml: col changed: h=25 // height excludes top_rect which was zero-size at that point
qml: col changed: iw=200 // bottom_rect retained its size so col isn't zero-sized 

//...and so surrounding elements are updated
qml: blue_rect changed: w=200
qml: blue_rect changed: iw=200
qml: blue_rect w=200 h=0 iw=200 ih=0

//...next col decides to update its implicitHeight 
qml: col changed: ih=25
qml: col w=200 h=25 iw=200 ih=25
//...which causes a second layout of surroundings:
qml: blue_rect changed: h=25
qml: blue_rect changed: ih=25
qml: blue_rect w=200 h=25 iw=200 ih=25

qml: green_rect changed: w=500
qml: green_rect changed: h=500
qml: green_rect w=500 h=500 iw=0 ih=0

//This is apparently col getting the second update of top_rect:
qml: col changed: h=60 //height now includes non-zero-sized top_rect
qml: col changed: ih=60
qml: col w=200 h=60 iw=200 ih=60

//...so blue_rect is changed yet again:
qml: blue_rect changed: h=60
qml: blue_rect changed: ih=60
qml: blue_rect w=200 h=60 iw=200 ih=60
```

Result:

```
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

#### Both uncommented:

```
// col is zero-sized still so children cling to its zero-size
qml: bottom_rect changed: w=0   col.w=0
qml: bottom_rect w=0 h=26 iw=200 ih=26
qml: top_rect changed: w=0   col.w=0
qml: top_rect w=0 h=24 iw=100 ih=24

// because all children are zero-sized, col is also zero-sized so it doesn't attempt to do anything

// because col is zero-sized, blue_rect also remains zero-sized

qml: green_rect changed: w=500
qml: green_rect changed: h=500
qml: green_rect w=500 h=500 iw=0 ih=0
```

Result: green window

#### Conclusion

Column width depends on largest element width but element width is anchored to column so it has a chicken-and-egg-problem but since it's indirect and also causes initial zero size to persist, Qt cannot detect a binding loop and instead the elements remain collapsed.

This effectively means that QtQuick is not "smart" enough to properly position items in this case. You have to either specify actual width for one of the items or the column.

`ColumnLayout` is a bit smarter in that it can have minimum, maximum and preferred sizes specified so you should probably use it instead of `Column`. I understand you already figured out how to use it so I won't go into details here.

Alternatively, imperative code could be used to determine largest of the elements' width and set col's width to that. It can also set other elements' width if desired.

Answer (score 1):

QML Column is more like a positioner and in my case it is not very good in resizing its children.

Experimented with ColumnLayout which somewhat solves the issue, but produces a lot of warning messages because ColumnLayout is not directly, but derived from QQuickLayout where anchoring is checked and dumps this warning message: "Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead."

Finally, I have made a workaround in QML which utilizes uniform padding and spacing between the elements whose implicitHeight is larger than zero.

It can be used as a regular QML element.

*This is a modified answer based on the suggestions of Jack White.*

```
MyColumn.qml:

import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle
{
    default property alias data2: container.data

    property int spacing: 0
    property int padding: 0

    implicitWidth: container.implicitWidth + 2*padding
    implicitHeight: container.implicitHeight + 2*padding

    data:
    [
        Item
        {
            id: container

            property int spacing: parent.spacing

            function implicitHeightOfChildren() {
                var total = 0
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++)
                    total += children[i].implicitHeight
                return total
            }

            function widestChild() {
                var max = 0
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++)
                    if(children[i].implicitWidth > max)
                        max = children[i].implicitWidth
                return max
            }

            function calculateSpacing() {
                var itemsWithHeight = 0
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                    if(children[i].implicitHeight > 0)
                        itemsWithHeight++
                return (itemsWithHeight > 0 ? (itemsWithHeight - 1) * spacing : 0)
            }

            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: parent.padding
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: parent.padding
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: parent.padding

            implicitWidth: widestChild()
            implicitHeight: implicitHeightOfChildren() + calculateSpacing()

            onChildrenChanged:
            {
                for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
                    if(i === 0) {
                        children[i].anchors.top = Qt.binding(function() { return children[i].parent.top });
                    } else {
                        children[i].anchors.top = Qt.binding(function() { return children[i-1].bottom });
                        children[i].anchors.topMargin = (children[i-1].implicitHeight > 0 ? spacing : 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Example use without anchoring to the column. Uncomment the anchor lines to see the expected behavior.

```
MyColumn {
    color: "red"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    Repeater {
        model: 3
        Rectangle {
            //anchors.left: parent.left
            //anchors.right: parent.right
            implicitWidth: 100 + 25 * index
            implicitHeight: 25
            color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: using anchors vs not using anchors]

Comment: Please note that, as far as I know, QML does not guarantee which `Component.onCompleted` runs first, so there is no telling if reparenting completes in before calculation. Furthermore, elements can be added after Component is completed, such as with a `Repeater`. I'm not sure if outer rectangle is necessary, but if it is, try this: `Rectangle { default property alias data2: col.data; data: [ Column { id: col; onDataChanged: { ...calculate sizes... } } ] } ` - this makes all elements inserted in `Rectangle` actually children of `Column` and recalculates sizes as children are inserted/removed

Comment: You are right about the order of execution of onCompleted handlers. Btw I'm using Repeater in MyColumn in a test code now and things are working well. Your approach about using QQuickItem::data property is not bad idea, but have you ever used it like this?

Comment: This is normal QML syntax. Although I don't remember using that kind of code until now I don't think there is anything wrong with it. Because I ran out of character limit while trying to post the explanation as a comment, I posted it a yet another answer. If your issue is resolved, please mark one of the answers (probably your own answer) as accepted to specify you don't need any more answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a pure C++ solution which works well in our project environment.

TheColumn.h

```
#ifndef THECOLUMN_H
#define THECOLUMN_H

#include <QQuickItem>

class TheColumn : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal spacing READ spacing WRITE setSpacing NOTIFY spacingChanged)

public:
    explicit TheColumn(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);
    ~TheColumn();

    qreal spacing() const;
    void setSpacing(qreal r);

    void positionItems();
    void componentComplete() override;
    void itemChange(ItemChange, const ItemChangeData &) override;

Q_SIGNALS:
    void spacingChanged();

public slots:
    void onChildImplicitWidthChanged();
    void onChildImplicitHeightChanged();

private:
    qreal mSpacing;
};

#endif // THECOLUMN_H
```

TheColumn.cpp

```
#include "thecolumn.h"

TheColumn::TheColumn(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickItem{ parent }, mSpacing{ 0.0 }
{
    setFlag(ItemHasContents, true);
}

TheColumn::~TheColumn()
{
}

qreal TheColumn::spacing() const
{
    return mSpacing;
}

void TheColumn::setSpacing(qreal s)
{
    if (mSpacing == s) return;
    mSpacing = s;

    Q_EMIT spacingChanged();

    if(isComponentComplete())
        positionItems();
}

void TheColumn::positionItems()
{
    qreal maxImplicitWidth = 0.0;
    qreal totalImplicitHeight = 0.0;

    QList<QQuickItem*> children = childItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.count(); ++i) {
        QQuickItem *child = children.at(i);

        child->setY(totalImplicitHeight);

        if(child->implicitWidth() > maxImplicitWidth)
            maxImplicitWidth = child->implicitWidth();
        if(child->implicitHeight() > 0) {
            totalImplicitHeight += child->implicitHeight();
            totalImplicitHeight += mSpacing;
        }
    }

    totalImplicitHeight -= mSpacing;

    setImplicitWidth(maxImplicitWidth);
    setImplicitHeight(totalImplicitHeight);
}

void TheColumn::componentComplete()
{
    positionItems();
    QQuickItem::componentComplete();
}

void TheColumn::onChildImplicitWidthChanged()
{
    positionItems();
}

void TheColumn::onChildImplicitHeightChanged()
{
    positionItems();
}

void TheColumn::itemChange(ItemChange change, const ItemChangeData &value)
{
    if(change == ItemChildAddedChange) {
        QObject::connect(value.item, &QQuickItem::implicitWidthChanged, this, &TheColumn::onChildImplicitWidthChanged);
        QObject::connect(value.item, &QQuickItem::implicitHeightChanged, this, &TheColumn::onChildImplicitHeightChanged);
    }
    QQuickItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

This type must be registered for somewhere, for example:
main.cpp

```
qmlRegisterType<TheColumn>("TheColumn", 1, 0, "TheColumn");
```

QML snippet:

```
import TheColumn 1.0

//boilerplate QML code

TheColumn {
    spacing: 10
    Repeater {
        model: 3
        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            implicitWidth: 100 + 25 * index
            implicitHeight: 25
            color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a apearnt loop between your second rectangle and the column inside. lets assume that the total width of elements inside column is 310 then you said to column that create a padding and the padding is inside the border of element (here the column). before having the padding the size of inner elements and the size of column should be calculated. because the size of the column is related to the size of the outer Rectangle and because of this:
`implicitWidth: col.implicitWidth implicitHeight: col.implicitHeight`
the size of the outer rectangle is related to the size of column there we have a endless loop.